# VBA: Suppress "Expected: expression" Msgbox

Tags: vba

When I'm working with VBA I'll sometimes leave a line of code incomplete to work on some other line.

Then I'll get the Msgbox "Compile Error: Expected: expression", and the line I just left will be red.

How do I suppress the MsgBox, yet still have the code go red?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only do it globally;

*Tools* > *Options* > *Editor* & de-select *Auto Syntax Check*

You will get the visual warning but no msgbox

Comment: Thanks for adding the detail: *"You will get the visual warning but no msgbox"*.